# What are "Invisible Columns" and how are they used?

Tags: mariadb, terminology, mariadb-10.3

I saw a new feature [Invisible Columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/) in MariaDB 10.3.x. What are practical use cases for DBA and web developer? When to use this feature?

> Columns can be given an `INVISIBLE` attribute in a `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER
>   TABLE` statement. These columns will then not be listed in the results
>   of a `SELECT *` statement, nor do they need to be assigned a value in an
>   `INSERT` statement, unless `INSERT` explicitly mentions them by name.
>
> Since `SELECT *` does not return the invisible columns, new tables or
>   views created in this manner will have no trace of the invisible
>   columns. If specifically referenced in the `SELECT` statement, the
>   columns will be brought into the view/new table, but the `INVISIBLE`
>   attribute will not.
>
> Invisible columns can be declared as `NOT NULL`, but then require a
>   `DEFAULT` value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is of course not standard SQL, and generally goofy. Instead follow best practices,

1. **Never** use `INVISIBLE` columns.
2. **Never** use `SELECT *` in production code.
3. **Always** secure columns that you don't want other people to get access to with encryption, or [SQL-Standard column-level permissions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/grant/#column-privileges).

## MariaDB's `INVISIBLE` Columns

It seems that the intention is to permit MariaDB users to continue to use `SELECT *` which is *almost* always against a DBA's best practices. So now you can use `SELECT *`, and then add to the table without mutating the result returned by `SELECT *`.

```
CREATE TABLE users ( id INT, username varchar(255) );
```

And you have an export that dumps `users` with `SELECT *`. Later if you wish to add a column, you can mark it as `INVISIBLE` and maintain the result

```
ALERT TABLE users
  ADD COLUMN password varchar(255) INVISIBLE;
```

Post- `ADD COLUMN` you're still *hilariously* safe without learning that no one in their right mind would use `SELECT *` for in that case.

Though only one type of invisibility is exposed to the user, MariaDB internally has four different types of invisibility. For more information see, [MDEV-10177 Invisible columns](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-10177). **Invisibility also effects `INSERT`, find more information on the ticket**

## Other Databases

As an aside, [Oracle calls this feature `INVISIBLE`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/invisible-columns-12cr1), and [DB2 calls it `IMPLICITLY HIDDEN`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/c0059345.html). In other dialects of SQL where this isn't supported you would just create a `VIEW`,

```
CREATE user_view AS SELECT id, username FROM users;
```

Comment: It is reasonable to ask a single person not to use SELECT *. But a company mainly uses SELECT *. It doesn't matter how hard you try and how right you are - you will not be able to change this situation.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an actual use-case that came up just days after I learned about the invisible columns feature in MariaDB 10.3:

Following a new requirement, I had added a new column in the middle of one of our big tables. (This is accessed by multiple different applications.) While this is the kind of menial task that you wouldn't imagine could result in a problem even in your worst nightmares, this is exactly what happened.

Unbeknownst to me, we had some "innovative" legacy code that was executing `SELECT *` against that particular table (and several others, it turns out), and then populating a set of variables based on the column names and column order that existed at the time. The end result was that the wrong values were displayed in the user interface, causing much confusion with the users.

I could have fixed the issue in minutes by making the column "invisible", but since we were still running 10.2 that wasn't an option, so we decided to go the hard route by patching and re-deploying the software. Had we not had access to the source code or for other reasons not been able to modify the code, an upgrade to 10.3 could have been our only option.

So while this feature is not covered by the SQL Standard, it can nevertheless be useful in some rare cases.

Comment: I think this is still under the umbrella of permitting users to *not* follow best-practices. `SELECT *` is simply not a good idea. just think about how confusing it'll be when someone later goes to see what columns are in the table and assumes the list of columns returned is all there is and builds something around it. Or adds another `INVISIBLE` column.

Comment: Under this definition `INVISIBLE` is essentially a flag "we engineered something wrong and don't want to fix it." It says *nothing* about the column itself.

Comment: @EvanCarroll Yes, I agree obviously that `SELECT *` is not best practice, but in an operational environment the main concern when something is broken is usually to restore operations a.s.a.p., not to achieve SQL Standards purity. It's not that they don't want to fix the issue properly, just that it's not possible at the moment, and also not the most pressing concern.

Comment: In my understanding the main problem was not SELECT *, but bad code that didn't assign variables properly. Correct?

Comment: @FedericoRazzoli - Yes, in my use-case above, I guess the issue was not `SELECT *` in itself, but the code that assumed the column order would never change, and didn't interpret the result set based on the actual column names returned. Of course, had they specified each column in the `SELECT`, then the problem would have been avoided.

Comment: Yes of course. But SELECT * is a very common practice, and I doubt that we will ever be able to stop it.